# How do I find the index of a particular element within a List in DAML?

Tags: daml

Say I have a List that looks like this:

```hs
let identifiers = ["ABC123", "DEF456", "GHI789"]
```

I want to know the index if the element "DEF456". What's the recommended way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `daml 1.2` you can use the `elemIndex : Eq a => a -> [a] -> Optional Int` function in the `DA.List` standard library module like so:

```
daml 1.2 module MyModule where

import DA.List

indexOfElement = scenario do
  let identifiers = ["ABC123", "DEF456", "GHI789"]
      index : Optional Int = elemIndex "DEF456" identifiers
  assert $ index == Some 1
  return index
```

Answer (score 2):

The `findIndex` function in the `Base.List` module in the standard library, does what you want.

```
daml 1.0 module FindIndex where

import Base.List
import Base.Maybe

test foo : Scenario {} = scenario
  let
    identifiers = ["ABC123", "DEF456", "GHI789"]
    index: Maybe Integer = findIndex ((==) "DEF456") identifiers

  assert $ index == Just 1
```

Under the hood most list manipulation in DAML, including `findIndex` is implemented using `foldr` and `foldl`.

```
-- Returns the index of the first element in the list satisfying the predicate, or M.Nothing if there is no such element.
def findIndex (f: a -> Bool) (xs: List a) : Maybe Integer =
  headMay (findIndices f xs)

-- Returns the indices of all elements satisfying the predicate, in ascending order.
def findIndices (f: a -> Bool) (xs: List a) =
  let work acc x =
        let i = fst acc
        let is = snd acc
        tuple (i + 1) (if f x then cons i is else is)
  reverse (snd (foldl work (tuple 0 nil) xs))
```